# Selenium on Python unable to locate nested class element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, class

I'm trying to reach a nested  class, originally I used xPath but it returned an empty list, so I went through the classes individually, and one of them has an issue where selenium can't find it.

Up until `Price4` it works fine, but it can't seem to find `Price5`

[image: up until Price4 it works fine, but it can't seem to find Price5]

[image: This is the website's inspector]

Comment: Looks like you need to locate the elements not just by their class name.  
Please provide the link to the page you are working on and I'll try to give you better locators

Comment: https://p2p.binance.com/en I personally couldn't find any locators aside from the class name, but ultimately the goal is to read the price text

Comment: I see all the elements containing the price are located by the same class name .css-1m1f8hn

Comment: Please let me know if this helped you. Otherwise will try to help more.

Comment: I only need to read the first one, the lowest. But you are right, they all have the same name, it's just the parent classes that are different.

Comment: (//*[@class='css-1m1f8hn'])[last()]

Comment: Is this what you are looked for?

Comment: It found it! but when I print it it prints in the form of [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bcbc5d88fb26c76ac69c1feeec8494cc", element="79ed51eb-c91a-4895-82b1-193a738857cc")>]
Any idea on how to show the value itself?

Comment: What / how are you printing it?
You have to `driver.findElement(element).getText()` where `element` is currently `By.xpath((//*[@class='css-1m1f8hn'])[last()])`

Comment: currently this is how I have it set up `Test = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[@class='css-1m1f8hn'])[last()]")` and `Current= browser.find_element(Test).text` with `print(Current)`, but it's yielding an error: "'list' object has no attribute 'text'" on the xPath line

Comment: it looks like text, not `value` attribute   
if it was an attribute you could use something like  
`driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getAttribute(attribute)`  
where `xpath` is the `xpath` locator and the `attribute` is the element attribute name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to get the text from the last element containing the price you can define
`String lastPriceXpath = "(//*[@class='css-1m1f8hn'])[last()]"`
`String lastPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath(lastPriceXpath)).getText()`

The syntax above is in `Java` but I hope you will be able to convert it to `python`, it's quite similar

Comment: It finally worked, thank you so much, and for reference below is the Python equivalent

Comment: `Test = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("(//*[@class='css-1m1f8hn'])[1]")`

            `for value in Test: print(value.text)`